# What value will I get if not call setValueForKey first?

Tags: ios, objective-c, kvc

I set up 3 `UITextField` in my viewController.

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UITextField *line1;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UITextField *line2;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UITextField *line3;
```

And I try to get the value for key:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    NSString *fieldName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"line%d",i ];
    UITextField *theField = [self valueForKey:fieldName];
    NSLog(@"TEXTFIELD : %@",theField);
}
```

And I got all UITextFields.

```
2015-03-03 10:32:32.776 KVCTEST[26691:1586602] TEXTFIELD : <UITextField: 0x7f9a00e1c5c0; frame = (50 120; 220 30); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9a00e1ae40>>
2015-03-03 10:32:32.777 KVCTEST[26691:1586602] TEXTFIELD : <UITextField: 0x7f9a00f1b920; frame = (50 160; 220 30); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9a00f1bb80>>
2015-03-03 10:32:32.777 KVCTEST[26691:1586602] TEXTFIELD : <UITextField: 0x7f9a00f1d330; frame = (50 200; 220 30); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9a00f1d590>>
```

But if I changed the instance variable name to e.g. `LINE1`, `LINE2`, `LINE3`, exception will raise.

So is the key-value-coding will associate with the name of the ivar by default? And I don't have to `setValueForKey` first?

Comment: Your answer is under `Default Search Pattern for valueForKey:` in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer to this can be found in the [Apple documentation regarding KVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170-BAJEAIEE).

> A key is a string that identifies a specific property of an object.
>   Typically, a key corresponds to the name of an accessor method or
>   instance variable in the receiving object. Keys must use ASCII
>   encoding, **begin with a lowercase letter**, and may not contain
>   whitespace.